# Can't get .net Core 3.1 App deployed with dotnet publish nor msbuild

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-publish

I stumble around a whole day trying to get a .net Core 3.1 App deployed with Jenkins.

My solution until today was:

```
dotnet publish "git/%SolutionPath%" -o "%WORKSPACE%/output/" -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained true
```

Today I had a new app an an error:

```
error : MSB4803: The task "ResolveComReference" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details
```

So I started to try to switch from `dotnet publish` to `msbuild` - and the hell began. After dozens of errors, missing environment variales and other things I'm stuck with this runtime error.

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (SgbAppInstaller.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'PropertyChanged.Fody', version: '3.2.6'
path: 'lib/netstandard1.0/PropertyChanged.dll'
```

I just want to compile my program. I really didn't expect it to be complicated.

The only thing I found to this topic is: Do not use msbuild, use donet publish for .net Core

Comment: Maybe the best way for me is to try to get rid of Com.